# Is it possible to render an LWC template identfied by file name that is only known at runtime?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

This [Render Multiple Templates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.create_render) code example shows how to pull content from multiple `.html` files in the same component:

```
import { LightningElement, track  } from 'lwc';
import templateOne from './templateOne.html';
import templateTwo from './templateTwo.html';

export default class MultipleTemplates extends LightningElement {

    @track templateOne = true;

    render() {
        return this.templateOne ? templateOne : templateTwo;
    }

    switchTemplate(){ 
        this.templateOne = this.templateOne === true ? false : true; 
    }
}
```

and this mechanism works well.

But in some circumstances, we would like to allow our customers to replace the `.html` content with their own (customized) version. When a Google "dynamic import", I get lost pretty quickly on what is and is not allowed in JavaScript, and then there is what LWC might or might not allow.

Is there a solution in LWC to vary the `.html` used at runtime?

Comment: You have to be able to statically link templates for now. You can choose from templates that you have control over, but you can't do so dynamically via a string. You would need to use Aura for now to load components dynamically. See the linked question/answers for more info.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks. Was vaguely hoping that varying the template is different to dynamically creating a component.

Comment: For what it's worth, the PM has stated that there *may* be a path to do this in the future. Unfortunately, it's simply not available for now.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for this great info.